# SWIFT: Tapping a UIButton really fast results in incorrect vote count

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I've created a simple song list app below.

[image]

It works as follows: 
1. Users can add songs to the list (using the '+' icon)
2. Uses can click to the vote button to increase or decrease their vote by one. It works similar to the 'LIKE' button on Facebook.

As you can see, some of the vote counts are negative numbers.  The reason for this is because during QA, I clicked the 'Vote' button extremely fast and it causes the vote count to go haywire. I do not see this as being a scenario that would occur a lot, but does anyone have a creative way to prevent this from happening? Any solutions would be appreciated. Thanks.

I can add my code if it's required, but I am hoping that there is a simple solution to this that I haven't found as yet.

**UPDATE**: Added code for the Table View Controller and the Table View Cell -

Table View Cell (with UIButton Action for 'vote'):

```
@IBAction func voteButton(sender: UIButton) {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"UserVotes")

    //query the database to check if the user actually like the song in the paticular row that's clicked
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    query.whereKey("song", equalTo: songID!)
    query.whereKey("vote", equalTo: true)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            //this is the case where a TRUE value is found. LIKE is ON
            if object!.count > 0 {

                if let object = object! as? [PFObject] {

                    for object in object {

                        if self.delegate != nil && self.rowValue != nil {

                            //decrease the count by 1
                            self.voteCount = self.voteCount! - 1
                            self.votes.text = "\(self.voteCount!)"

                            self.voteButtonOn = true
                            self.delegate!.voteButtonTurnOffFromCellRow(self.rowValue!)
                            print(self.voteButtonOn)
                        }

                    }
                }

            //this is the case where a TRUE value is NOT found, LIKE is OFF.
            } else if object?.count == 0 {

                if self.delegate != nil && self.rowValue != nil {

                    //increase the count by 1
                    self.voteCount = self.voteCount! + 1
                    self.votes.text = "\(self.voteCount!)"

                    self.voteButtonOn = false
                    self.delegate!.voteButtonTurnOnFromCellRow(self.rowValue!)
                    print(self.voteButtonOn)

                }
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Table View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

protocol VoteProtocol {
    func voteButtonTurnOnFromCellRow(row: Int)
    func voteButtonTurnOffFromCellRow(row: Int)
}

class MusicPlaylistTableViewController: UITableViewController, VoteProtocol {

var usernames = [String]()
var songs = [String]()
var songVotes = [Int]()

//Function to display an alert
func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    let query = PFQuery(className:"PlaylistData")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                self.usernames.removeAll()
                self.songs.removeAll()

                for object in objects {

                    let username = object["username"] as? String
                    self.usernames.append(username!)

                    let track = object["song"] as? String
                    self.songs.append(track!)

                    let votes = object["numVotes"] as? Int
                    self.songVotes.append(votes!)                        
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return usernames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTrack", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TrackTableViewCell

    cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row]

    var voteCount: Int = songVotes[indexPath.row]
    var voteCountString = String(voteCount)
    cell.votes.text = voteCountString

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.rowValue = indexPath.row
    cell.songID = songs[indexPath.row]
    cell.voteCount = songVotes[indexPath.row]

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



}

//If the LIKE button is OFF perform this. This means that a record in the database has NOT been found with a value of TRUE.
func voteButtonTurnOnFromCellRow(var row: Int) {

    // At this point, the value needs to be changed to TRUE, and the vote count needs to be increased by 1.
    //note: does not take into account scenario where there are duplicate records (slight case)
    let query = PFQuery(className:"UserVotes")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    query.whereKey("song", equalTo: songs[row])
    query.whereKey("vote", equalTo: false)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


        if error == nil {

            //this is the case where a FALSE value is found. LIKE is OFF
            if object!.count > 0 {

                if let object = object! as? [PFObject] {

                    for object in object {

                        object["vote"] = true
                        object.saveInBackground()

                        let query = PFQuery(className:"PlaylistData")
                        query.whereKey("song", equalTo: self.songs[row])

                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                            if error == nil {

                                if let object = object! as? [PFObject] {

                                    for object in object {

                                        var voteCount:Int = object["numVotes"] as! Int
                                        voteCount = voteCount + 1
                                        object["numVotes"] = voteCount
                                        object.saveInBackground()
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            //this is the case where a TRUE value is NOT found, LIKE is OFF (first time user vote)
            } else if object?.count == 0 {

                //add row to table
                let addUserVote = PFObject(className: "UserVotes")

                addUserVote["song"] = self.songs[row]
                addUserVote["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
                addUserVote["vote"] = true

                addUserVote.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if (success) {

                        if let error = error {
                            if let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                                self.displayAlert("Error", message: errorString)

                            }


                        } else {

                            let query = PFQuery(className:"PlaylistData")
                            query.whereKey("song", equalTo: self.songs[row])

                            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                                if error == nil {

                                    if let object = object! as? [PFObject] {

                                        for object in object {

                                            var voteCount:Int = object["numVotes"] as! Int
                                            voteCount = voteCount + 1
                                            object["numVotes"] = voteCount
                                            object.saveInBackground()
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }


                    } else {

                        // There was a problem, check error.description

                    }
                }



            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }

    }

}

//If the LIKE button is ON perform this. This means that a record in the database has been found with a value of TRUE.
func voteButtonTurnOffFromCellRow(var row: Int) {

    // At this point, the value needs to be changed to FALSE, and the vote count needs to be decreased by 1.

    //note: does not take into account scenario where there are duplicate records (slight case)
    let query = PFQuery(className:"UserVotes")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    query.whereKey("song", equalTo: songs[row])
    query.whereKey("vote", equalTo: true)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let object = object! as? [PFObject] {

                for object in object {

                    object["vote"] = false
                    object.saveInBackground()

                    let query = PFQuery(className:"PlaylistData")
                    query.whereKey("song", equalTo: self.songs[row])

                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {

                            if let object = object! as? [PFObject] {

                                for object in object {

                                    var voteCount:Int = object["numVotes"] as! Int
                                    voteCount = voteCount - 1
                                    object["numVotes"] = voteCount
                                    object.saveInBackground()
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            } else {

                print(error)
            }
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Add some code , you might be doing something not right !

Comment: @AaoIi I just added my code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: So in the normal cases it works if you pressed it ? It's just because your tapping quickly ?

Comment: well what action your doing when the count becomes 0 ? I can see your not checking the current count ! Your only checking the object count ! I'll look more at it when I get back to my laptop !

Comment: @AaoIi any more ideas about this one? I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In your button action toggle button userInteractionEnabled property to NO at the beginning and to YES at the end of the method. This may help you

Comment: @harsha_yarabarla. Thanks for your suggestion.  Can you be a bit more description on exactly where this would go in my code?  Thanks.